# manual sync of data in android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to limit the synchronization of firebase in android platform to only sync when the internet connection is WIFI programmatically.  In android I could check what type of connection is being used but since firebase uploads the data automatically, I cannot use the internet check condition.  I need a way to pause and resume the synchronization process of firebase.

I am referring to this link for the internet type conditions. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

Comment: You could go to your app settings and restrict background data. Not sure if that's the same thing, though

Comment: If you detect the type of network you want, you can use Firebase's [`goOffline()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_goOffline) and `goOnline()` method to explicitly manage the connection.